# TFS variable update, variable split

Tags: powershell, variables, tfs

I have a questions about Team Foundation Server variables:

1. Is there a way to update/define TFS variables from a PowerShell script (runs as a custom build step)?
2. When I define a variable value like "a,b,c" and I want to use it in a build step which wants it as a multiline value (separated by \n) is there a way to split it online, like `Projects: $(myVariable).split(',')` ?
3. Can I define multiline-type variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Variables are name-value pairs defined by you or provided by Build or Release Management. You can use variables as inputs and in your scripts. Check:　https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables
2. One variable usually has one value. But your requirement should can be achieved with Poswershell script, you need to refer to Powershell documentation to implement how to split values.
3. No. Never seen such definition.

Comment: 1. so you say I cannot change a variable value in a build step?
2. Misunderstand: I know how to split in my script, but another script (like "copy artifacts") needs newline-separated value, meanwhile I have a comma separated value. My question is about how to insert a comma-separated value as an input where a newline-separated value is accepted. Thank you for your answer.